# RACObserve subscribeNext get called instantly

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I'm using ReactiveCocoa 2.5 because I need to support iOS 7. I'm new at ReactiveCocoa. I've write this code:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[RACObserve(_currentUser, username) subscribeNext:^(NSString *newUsername) {
    [weakSelf performSelector:@selector(saveUserChanges) withObject:nil afterDelay:.1];
}];
```

And `subscribeNext` block get called instantly. `_currentUser`'s `username` property not changed after I call `RACObserve subscribeNext`. Maybe it's normal behaviour and `subscribeNext` should get called first time after starting to observe? If it's normal how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is normal -- signals created via `RACObserve` will always send their initial values immediately. If you only want subsequent values, you can skip the initial value like so:

```
[[RACObserve(_currentUser, username) skip:1] subscribeNext:^(NSString *newUserName) {
    [weakSelf performSelector:@selector(saveUserChanges) withObject:nil afterDelay:.1];
}];
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Should I write this line before `RACObserve subscribeNext:` or after?

Comment: I've tried both but it didn't help. I suppose I should use `[RACObserve(_currentUser, username) skip:1]` in some other way?

Comment: @tagirkaZ You want to subscribe to the signal returned by the `skip` call. I've edited my answer to be more clear.